# how I can get label name when user click on particular area in doughnut chart.js? I am not able to find the index of selected area for chart.js

Tags: laravel, chart.js, laravel-blade

I am using chart.js, Laravel 5.4 and blade templates.
I have to show doughnut chart and when user click on particular area then it should show the name of selected label and value belongs to it in the modal but firstly I am not able to get label name when user click on doughnut chart.

```
<br>var bookings = {!! json_encode($bookings)  !!} ;
<br>var map={"confirmed":{"label":"Confirmed","color":"#4BC0C0"},"cancelled":{"label":"Cancelled","color":"#FFCD56"},"on_request":{"label":"On Request","color":"#FF6384"}}
 <br>@if($hasChart)
        <br>var labels=[],colors=[],numbers=[],hasChart=false;
        <br>for (var property in map) {
            <br>if(bookings[property].length>=0){
                <br>hasChart=true;
                        <br>labels.push(map[property]["label"]);
                        <br>colors.push(map[property]["color"]);
                          <br>numbers.push(bookings[property].length);
            }
        }        
 var ctx = document.getElementById('doughnut-chart').getContext('2d');
            <br>var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                 <br>type: 'doughnut',
                 <br>data: {
                     <br>labels: labels,
                     <br>datasets: [
                         <br>{
                            backgroundColor: colors,
                            data: numbers
                        }
                    ]
                 <br>},
                 <br>options:  {                     
                    onClick: (e) => {
                          <br>//to do get value of selected label
                        <br>$('#bookingInfoModal').modal('show');                     
                    },
                     <br>maintainAspectRatio: false,
                     <br>elements: {
                         <br>arc: {
                            borderWidth: 0
                        }
                    }, <br>
                     <br>plugins: {
                         <br>legend: {
                            display: true,
                            position: "right",
                            align: "end",
                            padding: 50,
                            labels: {
                                boxWidth: 10,
                                color: '#000000',
                            },
                         <br>},
                     <br>},
                 <br>},
             <br>});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. it's working now.

```
options: {
 onClick: (e,legend) => {
  console.log(legend[0].index);
  alert(chart.data.labels[legend[0].index]);
 },
}
```